# django registration inactive users overflow

Tags: django

Dear Everyone,
I recently launched a site and I am seeing a lot of inactive users in django's admin page. I am currently using django-registration which takes a really long time to set up and send email (send_mail). What are alternative solutions to this?

How can I keep an email connection active in django across different threads? Putting it in settings doesn't seem like a good idea

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the problem is caused by fact that django creates connection each time. You can install local smtp without auth and connect to it via localhost. It is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If installing local smtp is some sort of problem for you (eg you use windows desktop), you can use one from python libs: from base library or from Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

This [fork of django-registration](http://bitbucket.org/seanoc/django-registration) integrates with [django-mailer](https://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/) which uses background processes to send mail instead processing it during the HTTP request. Mail is sent out by a management command:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python2.5 manage.py send_mail
```

You schedule `cron` to run this command regularly, say every 5 minutes or so. It does mean a delay before the user receives their confirmation e-mail, but it will resolve problems caused by timeouts.

However, I have never encountered this kind of issue with SMTP before so unless your traffic is remarkable (and even then, really!) you shouldn't be encountering this issue. Check to make sure your SMTP configuration doesn't have some other problem with it. At a minimum, you can play around with django's `send_mail` command in the shell, as well as just running something like

```
$ date | mail youremail@domain.com
```

In the bash shell for the server.

I'm afraid this all assumes you are using a *nix server or similar. If you're using a Windows machine you'll have to look into other options, or at the very least implement this all somewhat differently.